# Pandas read in txt files that have columns of different lengths

Tags: pandas

I need to read in lots of sounding data that the columns in those data have different length (see the attached sounding file https://drive.google.com/open?id=1GVaKdp6J47nS_yDc1LEDnAAxeGF7lpZT): the first 3 rows have only 3 columns while the rest of rows have 11 columns

I tried reading them using `pandas.read_csv`:

`data = pd.read_csv('DNR-910.txt', skiprows = 5,  header = None, delimiter= '\s+')`

and I got: 
`ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 2 fields in line 9, saw 11`

My problem is actually similar to this post : [read txt file with different number of columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50042949/read-txt-file-with-different-number-of-columns), but it is solved in R

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55129640/read-csv-into-a-dataframe-with-varying-row-lengths-using-pandas Read in each line into a single field, then have pandas `str.split` expand to the correct DataFrame. There are other great alternatives in that post too. I suggest making as a duplicate of that one if something there solves your issue.

Comment: Yeah, thanks, that helps! I figured if I let Pandas know in advance the number of columns, it will auto fill the missing values with NaNs

Comment: Yup, I think that's the best alternative here since you seem to already know the max number of columns :D